# Should I be concerned about my iMac’s (Late 2014 27") GPU temperature?

Tags: mac, graphics-card, cpu, temperature

I have Boot Camp installed in my iMac and when I check the temperature in Windows, when idle the GPU temperature is around 84-88 C and this worries me.

When I open in macOS the temperature when idle becomes 55-60C which again is high.

I didn’t know this until recently buy when I use my iMac GPU temperature reaches around 95-100C which is too much.

My iMac specs are

- **Model**: Late 2014 27" 5k Retina Display
- **Storage**: 1TB
- **GPU**: AMD RADEON R9 M295X
- **RAM**: 32 GB
- **CPU**: Intel Core i7-4790k CPU @4.00 GHz

Comment: Are you experiencing any problems? You say “…becomes 55-60 celsius which again is high.” and then “…when i use my iMac GPU temperature reaches around 95-100 which is too much.” Too high for who and why? Those are normal operating temperatures for a GPU.

Comment: i game on it but those games are compatible under both minimum and recommended settings. Some times it automatically switches off and when i did some research i shuts down to prevent damage. I searched the idle temperatures and those are less than 45. Even the fans increase their speed and i can hear their loud noise

Comment: I don’t  think the temperatures are an issue. I think the overall system performance might be degraded from basic age and use. A 6 year old iMac is 6 years old. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is known for preferring more silent operation at expense of thermals so most macs easily hit 100 degrees C temperatures at both CPU and GPU.
When CPU/GPU is close to overheating - it will reduce its clock speeds and performance (exact temperature depends on vendor settings, but usually is in 80-100C range).

There're several things that you can do around this:

1. Make sure fans are clean and operational (with time radiators often clog up with dust which reduces airflow and efficiency)
2. Use some app to manually (or semi-automatically) increase fan speed
3. Employ additional external cooling